# Reactive Streams Design Patterns

Tags: system.reactive, reactive-programming

I'm currently looking forward to using Reactive Streams in one of the projects. I understand the basics of using an Observable and an Observer! I would like to know if there are any design patterns that I should consider. For example., are there any patterns that I could employ when it comes to error handling?

When my stream is connected to a client which is a REST endpoint, it could be that the upstream system is not yet ready to respond to my requests and if I have my Observable that calls this REST end-point every 2 seconds, how do I handle these empty responses that I get from the REST calls?

I'm basically looking for some good practices when using Reactive Streams! Any suggestions?

Comment: There is the [Design Guidelines](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=205219) document from Microsoft that can be helpful.

Comment: What language are you working in?

Comment: A `.Where(..)` clause can be used to filter out empty responses.

Comment: I use Scala predominantly!